# PHP: How to fix array_combine when one valus is empty

Tags: php, arrays

How to set a `= 0` value for each `checkbox` unchecked

**Error:**

```
Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in
```

**PHP:**

```
$combined = array_combine($_POST['name'], $_POST['day']);

foreach($combined as $name => $value) {
     echo $name.' => '.$value;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <form method="post" action="result.php">
  <p>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="seth" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="7" />
  </p>

  <p>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="jack" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="4" />
  </p>

  <p>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="david" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="3" />
  </p>

 </form>
```

**PS:** 
I won't use:

```
        <select name="day[]" size="1">
           <option value="0"> Non </option>
           <option value="1"> Yes </option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Hope this works for you. It's a bit more work then what you were hoping for probably.

**result.php**

```
<?PHP

$days = array();
$namecount = count($_POST['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $namecount; $i++){
    $days[$i] = isset($_POST['day'][$i]) ? $_POST['day'][$i] : 0;
}

$arr = array_combine($_POST['name'], $days);
print_r($arr);

?>
```

**form.html**

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="seth" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[0]" value="7" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="jack" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[1]" value="4" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="david" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[2]" value="3" />
    </p>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that unchecked checkboxes aren't even sent to the server, so as it is your 2 `$_POST` arrays won't line up unless they are all checked. You should consider using radios and setting the value of the key in `name` attribute.

ie do this for each input:

```
<form>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="name[3]" value="david" />
    <input type="radio" name="day[3]" value="yes" /> <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="day[3]" value="no" /><label>No</label>
</p>
</form>
```

Then do `print_r($_POST)` and you will see your arrays line up. Another way is to do a hidden input (with exactly the same `name=""` and it will act as a default value.

Comment: What I am saying is that if a user doesn't tick a checkbox and submit the form, it won't appear in your `$_POST` array.

Comment: @Naiimim What Dunhamzzz means is if a checkbox is unchecked, its not included in the $_POST request sent to the server, meaning instead of sending a false value indicating the check-box is unchecked, the browser sends nothing.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz when all checkbox are checkked I get the values. But when one is not checked is get the error above

Comment: @Saad Imran: Thanks I understand. How can I set a `0` value for this checkbox unsent - I tried to use isset() ...

Comment: @Naamim that's what I suggest you use Radios, or you can use hidden inputs, read the last line of my answer.

Comment: @Dunhamzz there is no other solution? :( I won't use `radio`

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only 3 ways:

1. Move to `<input type=radio>`s with the same name, this will give you extra control over the content that is sent through. (Given in a previous answer)
2. Add another input, a hidden one, `<input type=hidden>`, which has the same name as your checkbox, if the checkbox is not selected, the hidden input's value will be sent. (Given in a previous answer)
3. Use JavaScript to submit your form, and loop through the checkboxes to manually test each one for selected state, and send that along with the POST request.